# Activator.CreateInstance with custom class argument

Tags: c#, dll-injection, activator

I am trying to create a instance(Class Test) from dll by using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Class Test has one constructor which requires a arguement Class CommonService. But it throw `System.MissingMethodException` error.

There is the code:

```cs
// Define
public class Test: BaseTest
{
    public Test(CommonService commonService) : base(commonService, new TestConfigurations()
    {
       enableTimer = false
    })
    { 
    }
}

// Usage
var commonService = new CommonService();
var test = new Test(commonService); // test can be created successfully.

var dll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"xxx\Test.dll");
foreach (Type type in DLL.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (type.BaseType?.Name?.Equals("BaseTest") == true)
    {
        dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { // Throw System.MissingMethodException error
            commonService
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the full code link: https://codeshare.io/2EzrEv

Is there any suggestions about how to solve the problem?

Comment: This is *not* the code. If I supply all of the missing classes and fix the obvious compilation errors, the code seems to work. Can we have a [mcve] that you have actually compiled and run and know exhibits the problem you're trying to ask about?

Comment: Your class is called Test, but its constructor's name is AadjPlugin?

Comment: @o_w - that's one of the obvious errors but pointing out the specific errors just encourages minor corrections in the question rather than having them do us the courtesy of running it through an actual compiler and making sure the code exhibits the problem.

Comment: Are there other classes in your assembly derived from `BaseTest`?
Does `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test), new object[] { commonService });` work?

Comment: Sorry, the class is called Test, AadjPlugin is typo

Comment: But there's still an obvious compilation error in it. **please** take a bit of time and give us a compilable example that you *know* exhibits the problem you're trying to ask about.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the obvious compilation error was fixed a few minutes before your comment

Comment: @MarcGravell - no, there's still another obvious error in there. The OP has never run this code because it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the `dll`/`DLL`? ok, I'll grant you that one :) - I didn't notice because I deleted the external load from my code copy

Comment: And as pointed out in my second comment, and as the edit history bears out, if you do point out the specific error, all that happens is the asker fixes them in the question rather than making sure they're showing us code that they've seen cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Activator.CreateInstance` as shown: should work just fine. If it isn't, then the `type` you're initializing *might not be what you think it is* - check the value of `type.FullName`. Alternatively, it is possible that you have types *by the same name* in different locations, meaning: the `CommonService` that you're passing in *is not* the same as the `CommonService` that the type is expecting. You can check that with reflection. The following prints `True` twice:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class Test : BaseTest
{
    public Test(CommonService commonService) : base(commonService, new TestConfigurations()
    {
        enableTimer = false
    })
    {
    }
}

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Usage
        var commonService = new CommonService();
        var test = new Test(commonService); // test can be created successfully.

        var type = typeof(Test); // instead of loop
        dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { // Throw System.MissingMethodException error
            commonService
        });
        Console.WriteLine(c is object); // it worked

        var ctor = type.GetConstructors().Single();
        var ctorArg = ctor.GetParameters().Single();
        Console.WriteLine(ctorArg.ParameterType == typeof(CommonService)); // check the expected param type
    }
}
public class CommonService { }
public class TestConfigurations
{
    internal bool enableTimer;
}
public class BaseTest
{
    public BaseTest(CommonService svc, TestConfigurations cfg) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! using `var type = typeof(Test);` instead of loop can solve the problem

Comment: @StayReal well, that gets tricky; the reason I used that was that I don't have multiple dlls locally; if you already have a reference to the assembly where Test is defined, then fine - but that then prompts the question: why were you ever using `Assembly.Load`. The point of my answer here is that `Activator.CreateInstance` works fine.

Comment: Actually I just import Test directly for test purpose to indicate that the argument in constructor is CommonSerivce, but I can only use `Assembly.LoadFile` for production. After I separate CommonService from Test project and only build Test to a dll, it can works now. The minimal code pasted in https://codeshare.io/2EzrEv. Thanks for the help!